# Isn't it misleading to think of the optical image in the eye as a picture?

Tags: optics

I have looked at sources on optics and vision science which use the expressions “real optical image,” “optical image” or “retinal image” for the image which the optical system of the human eye projects onto the retina, and which either state or infer (by way of illustrations, pictures of optical images in pinhole cameras or eyes) that this image is a picture, a visual representation of the scene in front of the eye.

But surely an optical image as projected by a lens or lens system (or by a pinhole) is not, in itself, a picture, but a certain kind of two-dimensional distribution of visible EMR flowing through a plane in space, i.e. one in which the light energy at each point is coming from a single object point in 3D space lying in a single direction from the lens or pinhole, and which may or may not be projected onto a surface and reflected from it, and which may or may not then be reflected to the eyes of an observer.

Since the human eye evolved to form such as “image” of a scene on the retina, and since  this distribution of visible EMR is interpreted by the brain as the kind of distribution that it usually is (as defined above in my non-scientific way), when an observer looks at a surface that is reflecting one, and it’s re-projected onto the retina, then the brain interprets it in the same way, and the observer sees 3D objects. Then and only then does a picture come into being. That’s when picture perception take place, and only in the mind of the observer.

There is no little observer in the eye looking at the optical image on the retina, which in any case is being absorbed by the photoreceptor layer, not reflected from it.

Surely such optical images must have been formed perfectly well by small holes (as in pinhole images of the Sun under a tree) or (not so well) by translucent bits of rock (or water drops?) long before there was any such thing as a visual perceiver.

On a sunny day I can look out my bedroom window and see a sunny scene outside, or I can use a magnifying glass as a lens to project an inverted optical image of the scene onto the opposite wall.

As long as the lens is in place, each point on a small area of wall is receiving visible EMR from a single point in the scene (there’s an optical image there), and each point on the wall and is reflecting that EMR diffusely. When I look at that area of wall, the optical system of my eye focusses the EMR from each point on the wall to a single point on my retina, forming what my brain interprets as the optical image of a 3D scene, not an area of wall, and I see a picture of the scene.

In short (!), am I right in thinking that, without a visual perceiver, there may be “images” of objects in the sense of optical images (those patterns of EMR, projected on a wall, on the ground, or on a retina), but there is no such thing as an “image” in the sense of a visual representation or picture of objects?

Comment: This is a question of philosophy or definitions, not physics. As it is defined, a real image is an image. No observer or detector is necessary. But you are of course correct that if nobody perceives an image than no image is perceived.

Comment: Are you asking about the definition of "picture" or whether or not a real image is projected onto the retina or something else?   I can't tell exactly what your question is.

Comment: A way of putting it: A real optical image like the visual stimulus on the retina is made of, consists of a two-dimensional distribution of light energy, EMR, photons. A picture is made of matter; it's a surface that emits, reflects or transmits a real optical image (e.g., in order, a computer or phone screen, a painting or printed photo or opaque screen, and a translucent screen). A surface becomes a picture of objects when it emits, reflects of transmits to the eyes of an observer a real optical image of the objects and this is projected onto the retina by the optical system of the eye.

Comment: I've gone to the Psychology stack exchange. They say that I'm talking about the homunculus fallacy, and agree that the retinal image is not a thing that can be seen (such as a tree or a picture of a tree), it's a sensory stimulus. My point is that some of the sources on perception and even on optics that I've looked at slip into the homunculus fallacy.

Answer (score 1):

You are right. A screen that lights up when an image hits it is a better idea. The eye does have merit.

If you ignore the lens in your eye, the image forms on the retina. That is how you see it. True, it doesn't quite happen that way, but it still illustrates.

If you have a light bulb source and an eye image, it shows which way light travels through an optical system.

It certainly isn't the only less than perfectly accurate illustration of physics.